# Rails link_to not routing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ruby-on-rails

This is related to my previous post, I'm desperate and I'm sure this will have a simple solution, I just do not see how... I started **another project** with Ruby 2.7.2 and Rails 6.1.3. I'm using an accordion menu in the side bar but again, the 'link:to' just ignores the route... I have found that the Javascript visual effects (the accordion menu) and the modal in my previous post use the 'event.preventDefault()' to do it's visual magic... The weird thing here is that if I write the route in the browswer navigation it works... So it is just my code not working...The routes are gwenerated as usual with 'resources :users'...

```
     users GET    /users(.:format)            users#index
           POST   /users(.:format)            users#create
  new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)        users#new
 edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)   users#edit
      user GET    /users/:id(.:format)        users#show
           PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)        users#update
           PUT    /users/:id(.:format)        users#update
           DELETE /users/:id(.:format)        users#destroy
```

Here is the code...
The controller action: (app/controllers/users_controller.rb)

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]
  before_action :options

  # GET /users or /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
```

The hash to create the menu (app/controllers/application_controller.rb)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def options
    @options = [
      {:letrero => "Almacen", :submenu =>
        [
          {:opcion => "Entradas", :ruta => '#'}, 
          {:opcion => "Salidas", :ruta => '#'}
        ]
      },
      {:letrero => "Proveedores", :submenu =>
        [
          {:opcion => "Indice", :ruta => 'suppliers_path'}
        ]
      },
      {:letrero => "Productos", :submenu =>
        [
          {:opcion => "Index", :ruta => 'products_path'}, 
          {:opcion => "Autorización", :ruta => '#'}
        ]
      },
      {:letrero => "Usuarios", :submenu =>
        [
          {:opcion => "Indice", :ruta => 'users_url'}
        ]
      }
    ]
  end
end
```

The sidebar menu (app/views/static_pages/_sidebar.html.erb):

```
<ul class="menu">
  <% @options.each do |opcion| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to "#{opcion[:letrero]}<i class='icono derecha fas fa-chevron-down drop-down'></i>".html_safe, '#'%>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <% opcion[:submenu].each do |subopcion| %>
            <%= link_to subopcion[:opcion], eval(subopcion[:ruta]) %>
          <% end %>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

This is the app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>AlmacenCEB</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <%= favicon_link_tag %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-2/css/all.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <nav>sistema de caja</nav>
      <div class="main-w">Main
        <%= yield %>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="titulo">Menú principal</div>
        <%= render "static_pages/sideBar" %>
      </div>
      <footer>Footer</footer>
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

These are a couple images explaining the case
[image: The pointer shows the path to take]

[image: Writing the path in the browsers navigation works]

This is the app's repo: https://github.com/lflores1961/almacenCEB

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the `app/javascript/packs/static_pages.js` file, specifically with that [`e.preventDefault();`](https://github.com/lflores1961/almacenCEB/blob/main/app/javascript/packs/static_pages.js#L3) call you're preventing the click event be propagated to the `<a>` children.

Comment: I think you are right, I tried to include a ```e.stopPropagation()``` but not sure where or how to do that, I'm reading the documentation to learn more about it

Comment: @LuisFlores but why do you want to stop the event to be propagated?

Comment: I'm just guessing, I'm not that good with JavaScript... I'm watching some Youtube videos to try to understand, how it works

Comment: @LuisFlores cool. But at the end of the day, did removing that line fixed your issue with links? If so, consider to mark my answer as accepted, cheers

Comment: I tried taking that line out but the accordion menu effect stops working (I cannot see the options behind the main option) So, no this is not a solution, sorry for not responding timely. I guess I need to find out how to respond to the click after the accordion is displayed...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem in YouTube, I hope it helps anyone looking for similar problems, to be honest there is no problem but a lack of knowledge in JavaScript from my part... So here is the complete JavaScript function that must go in the app/javascript/packs/static_pages.js

```
$(function () {
  $('.menu li:has(ul)').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass('activado')) {
      $(this).removeClass('activado');
      $(this).children('ul').slideUp();
    } else {
      $('.menu li ul').slideUp();
      $('.menu li').removeClass('activado');
      $(this).addClass('activado');
      $(this).children('ul').slideDown();
    }
  });

  $(".menu li ul li a").on("click", function (e) {
    window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
  });
});
```

Thanks to Alter Lagos for providing orientation